# Requirejs with Knockout error: Unable to process binding "component: function (){return f}" - Mismatched anonymous defined() module

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

I'm getting the error across all browsers. I says "unable to process binding "component"...". I have read quite a number of articles including the requirejs site.  I've checked out what can cause the error but I'm lost as to whether they apply to my code or not. To the best of my knowledge, I'm not manually loading anything using the script tag and every module is loaded with requirejs.

I created a knockout project using yoman: `yo ko`. After that components are added using `yo ko:component [name of component]`. The page loads fine when the most of the time but periodically gives the error below. The frequency seems to be increased when I use two components. I edited the new component and removed the reference to the knockout object and the error still happens though not as frequently.

The exact error is as follows:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to process binding "component: function (){return f}"
Message: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (a){function b(a){return h.raw?a:encodeURIComponent(a)}function c(a){return h.raw?a:decodeURIComponent(a)}function d(a){return b(h.json?JSON.stringify(a):String(a))}function e(a){0===a.indexOf('"')&&(a=a.slice(1,-1).replace(/\\"/g,'"').replace(/\\\\/g,"\\"));try{return a=decodeURIComponent(a.replace(g," ")),h.json?JSON.parse(a):a}catch(b){}}function f(b,c){var d=h.raw?b:e(b);return a.isFunction(c)?c(d):d}var g=/\+/g,h=a.cookie=function(e,g,i){if(void 0!==g&&!a.isFunction(g)){if(i=a.extend({},h.defaults,i),"number"==typeof i.expires){var j=i.expires,k=i.expires=new Date;k.setTime(+k+864e5*j)}return document.cookie=[b(e),"=",d(g),i.expires?"; expires="+i.expires.toUTCString():"",i.path?"; path="+i.path:"",i.domain?"; domain="+i.domain:"",i.secure?"; secure":""].join("")}for(var l=e?void 0:{},m=document.cookie?document.cookie.split("; "):[],n=0,o=m.length;o>n;n++){var p=m[n].split("="),q=c(p.shift()),r=p.join("=");if(e&&e===q){l=f(r,g);break}e||void 0===(r=f(r))||(l[q]=r)}return l};h.defaults={},a.removeCookie=function(b,c){return void 0===a.cookie(b)?!1:(a.cookie(b,"",a.extend({},c,{expires:-1})),!a.cookie(b))}}
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
```

Below are some of the code in the files (if it helps)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>ko-cai</title>
    <!-- build:css -->
      <link href="bower_modules/semantic/dist/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="bower_modules/c3/c3.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:js -->
      <script src="app/require.config.js"></script>
      <script data-main="app/startup" src="bower_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <!--<side-bar></side-bar>
      <page-container></page-container>-->
      <dashboard></dashboard>
      this is a test
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

require.config.js

```
// require.js looks for the following global when initializing
var require = {
    baseUrl: ".",
    paths: {
        "crossroads":           "bower_modules/crossroads/dist/crossroads.min",
        "hasher":               "bower_modules/hasher/dist/js/hasher.min",
        "jquery":               "bower_modules/jquery/dist/jquery",
        "knockout":             "bower_modules/knockout/dist/knockout",
        "knockout-projections": "bower_modules/knockout-projections/dist/knockout-projections",
        "signals":              "bower_modules/js-signals/dist/signals.min",
        "text":                 "bower_modules/requirejs-text/text",
        "semantic":             "bower_modules/semantic/dist/semantic",
        "lodash":               "bower_modules/lodash/dist/lodash",
        "c3": "bower_modules/c3/c3",
        "d3": "bower_modules/d3/d3",
        "config":               "../../cai/config",
        "observations":         "../../cai/observations"
    },
    shim: {
        "semantic": { deps: ["jquery"] },
        "c3": { deps: ["d3"]},
        "config": { deps: ["knockout"]},
        "observations": { deps: ["knockout","jquery"]}
    }
};
```

dashboard.html

```
<h2>dashboard</h2>
<p data-bind='text: message'></p>
```

dashboard.ts

```
/// <amd-dependency path="text!./dashboard.html" />
import ko = require("knockout");
export var template: string = require("text!./dashboard.html");
export class viewModel {
    public message = ko.observable("Hello from the dashboard component too!");
    constructor (params: any) {
    }
    public dispose() {
        // This runs when the component is torn down. Put here any logic necessary to clean up,
        // for example cancelling setTimeouts or disposing Knockout subscriptions/computeds.
    }
}
```

dashboard.js

```
define(["require", "exports", "knockout", "text!./dashboard.html"], function(require, exports, ko) {
    exports.template = require("text!./dashboard.html");
    var viewModel = (function () {
        function viewModel(params) {
            this.message = ko.observable("Hello from the dashboard component too!");
        }
        viewModel.prototype.dispose = function () {
            // This runs when the component is torn down. Put here any logic necessary to clean up,
            // for example cancelling setTimeouts or disposing Knockout subscriptions/computeds.
        };
        return viewModel;
    })();
    exports.viewModel = viewModel;
});
//# sourceMappingURL=dashboard.js.map
```

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How do I fix this as it makes testing very difficult?
3. Where can I check which of the known issues apply to my code so I look for a fix.

Comment: What versions of requirejs and jquery are you using?

Comment: require.js is 2.1.15 and jQuery is 2.1.1. Knockout version is 3.2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more investigations, I was able to come up with a solution. May not be the best but I'm yet to see another. The problem had to do with require.js. It appears that it does not matter what is contained in the file (I even tried one with a blank function and got the mismatch error). I however noted that, when I execute the same require statement after the error, it actually works. I added a component loader to knockout to fetch the Config of the components. Below is the loader that worked for me. Hope it is useful to someone until a better solution is found or we get to the bottom of this issue.

```
//register a custom loader
ko.components.loaders.unshift({
getConfig: function(name,callback){
    ko.components.defaultLoader.getConfig(name, function(c){
    if (c && c.require){ //do custom loading here. make first attempt to fetch the config
        try{
        require([c.require],function(config){
            callback(config);
        });
        }catch(e){
        //todo: check that this is mismatch error and try again. else throw exception
        require([c.require], function(config){ //make the request again
            callback(config);
        });
        }
    } else {
        callback(c);
    }
    })
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the requirejs documentation? More precisely the list behind a link from the error you posted:

**To avoid the error:**

- Be sure to load all scripts that call define() via the RequireJS API.
  Do not manually code script tags in HTML to load scripts that have
  define() calls in them.
- If you manually code an HTML script tag, be sure it only includes
  named modules, and that an anonymous module that will have the same
  name as one of the modules in that file is not loaded.
- If the problem is the use of loader plugins or anonymous modules but
  the RequireJS optimizer is not used for file bundling, use the
  RequireJS optimizer.
- If the problem is the var define lint approach, use /*global define
  */ (no space before "global") comment style instead.

http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch

Comment: I have checked the documentation. The problem is I cannot determine which part of the code is violating any of the errors. Also, it is inconsistent and the portion of the application which I wrote does not do any of that. Do you know how to determine where any of these is violated?